# How to make makefile to use pattern rule?

Tags: makefile, rules

Having this simple makefile:

```
VPATH = include
CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -I include -Wall -pedantic

%: %.o include.o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

When I trigger it with the name of a program (the same name as is source with .c extension), I would expect to trigger the first rule (since I provided just a name *without* extension) and the the second one, because for the first rule, there is `%.o` prerequisite, which is exactly the second rule.

Having these file in pwd:

```
client.c  include  makefile  server6.c  server.c
```

Now If I make `make server`:
It does

```
gcc -I include -Wall -pedantic    server.c   -o server
```

In other words, The second rule is not triggered. there is no step with makeing object files, even though the object file is in the first rule as prerequisite. So how is that possible? The make is simply ignoring the prerequisite and trying to make just with the first rule. How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because make has a built-in rule for `%: %.c` and make [will always choose](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Match.html) a pattern rule that can directly create the target over a pattern rule that requires another pattern rule:

> Note however, that a rule whose prerequisites actually exist or are mentioned always takes priority over a rule with prerequisites that must be made by chaining other implicit rules.

You can run `make -r` to [remove all the built-in rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html), or else [remove it yourself](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canceling-Rules.html) by adding:

```
% : %.c
```

to your makefile.

You can see all built-in rules by running `make -p -f/dev/null`